# What's a good command line tool for updating app.config (.exe.config) files?

Tags: .net, windows, configuration

I have some key/value config values in a .Net app.config file

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="keyname" value="stringval" />
```

which I want to add or modify as part of a script after download. What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one option is to use Powershell. You can get things done with a pretty short script.

```
[xml] $xml = Get-Content "C:\tools\footools\foostable123\foo.exe.config"
$($xml.configuration.appSettings.add | Where-Object { $_.key -eq "TFSWorkItemUrl" }).value = "http://mytfsserveruri/"
$xml.Save("C:\temp.config")
```

The second line modifies the 'value' attribute of the xml element such as in the original question.
I do think there's going to be plentry of other good answers, so keep them coming - not everyone will prefer Powershell as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Read about XSL at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) . It does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: +0 I know what XSL is in theory, but I'm looking for recommendations of actual tools for executing it - or an alternative

Comment: What do you want to do in the app.config exactly? Is it an add,remove, or replace of an appSettings entry?

Comment: usually replace, sometimes add